# How to draw mouse-rotatable point cloud in python with vtk

Tags: python, vtk, point-clouds

I need to draw rotatable point cloud in python, here is what I've found on the net:

```
import vtk_visualizer as vv
import numpy as np
xyz = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
vtkControl = vv.VTKVisualizerControl()
vtkControl.AddPointCloudActor(xyz)
vtkControl.Render()
vtkControl.ResetCamera()
```

It shows window for few moments, but then window hides, so I can't rotate it with mouse. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution, which I've found:

```
import vtk_visualizer as vv
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
xyz = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
vtkControl = vv.VTKVisualizerControl()
vtkControl.AddPointCloudActor(xyz)
app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```